# Почему числа сравниваются неправильно?

Tags: c, сравнение

Почему числа сравниваются неправильно?

```
printf("%i\n",6==1==0); //1, а по идее должно быть 0, так как не равны
printf("%i\n",0==0==0); //0, по идее 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
6==1==0
```

выполняется как

```
(6==1)==0
```

Так как `6==1` - ложь, вычисление этого значения дает 0, которое при сравнении с 0 дает истину, т.е. 1.

Второй пример разберите сами - как `(0==0)==0`.

Comment: аа, я понял, а как лучше их сравнить?

Comment: или только (a==b)==(b==c)==(a==c)?

Comment: (a==b) && (b==c)

Answer (score 0):

Операнды вычисляются по очереди:

`(6==1)==0`,

`(0==0)==0`